# Excel : vlookup with non 1-1 match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet_1 with 2 columns :

e.a
COL_A                                 COL_B
ITM_RRT_Transaction_Status            Y/N
C991, no alarm from manager orion     Y/N
.....

I try to fill-in the COL_B based on a reference table in sheet_2 (match on both COL_A)

```
COL_A      COL_B  
ITM_RRT    Y  
no alarm   N
```

so sheet_2.COL_A value can be in any place within sheet_1.COL_A
how can I do ?
thanks for help

Comment: Can you match on the first (say) seven characters, or find a delimiter to split your lookup value?

Comment: So the COL_A values aren't the same in Sheet_1 and Sheet_2? How do they differ? Is there a pattern that differentiates them? Can you post a sample table of Sheet_2 and Sheet_1 with what you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

For `Vlookup(x,y,TRUE`,  your lookup table must be ***sorted ascending*** to work. That's how it goes for the `TRUE` in vlookup.

I don't know why the vlookup help page has changed, but [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) on the vlookup page, if you click "technical details"

> range_lookup   (optional)
>
> A logical value that specifies whether you want VLOOKUP to find an
>   approximate or an exact match:
>
> TRUE assumes the first column in the table is sorted either
>   numerically or alphabetically, and will then search for the closest
>   value. This is the default method if you don't specify one.
>
> FALSE searches for the exact value in the first column.

It can be better seen on [HLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> If range_lookup is TRUE, the values in the first row of table_array
>   must be placed in ascending order: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2,... , A-Z,
>   FALSE, TRUE; otherwise, HLOOKUP may not give the correct value. If
>   range_lookup is FALSE, table_array does not need to be sorted.

It's also present on the [LOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) page.

---

Also note that the same thing applies to a `MATCH` with `type: 1`. And a `MATCH` with `type: -1` requires the list to be ***sorted descending***.

**Only exact matches** can be found from *unsorted lists*.

Comment: thanks for help, but that string in sheet_2.COL_A can be in any place and any size within the string of sheet_1_COL_A. I try to sort sheet_2.COL_A and use vlookup (x,y, true) but didn't help if the string is inside. I complete the sample in original text

Comment: Then vlookup won't do what you want.